# how to change text color Opacity in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

how can i change the opacity of Text Color.White in JetPack Compose

```
Text(text = funfact , fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.White )
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change the alpha channel from the Color attribute:

```kotlin
Text(text = funfact, fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `alpha` modifier:

```
Text(
    text = funfact,
    modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.5f),
    fontSize = 18.sp,
    color = Color.White,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert the text component inside a `CompositionLocalProvider` as follows:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
    Text(text = "Your text")
}
```

`ContentAlpha` contains 3 default types of opacity: **medium**, **high** and **disabled**.

Tested on stable version of Compose 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set alpha for a Text using **Material Design standards**, a more direct and similar way to [@ReVs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988106/4398784) is:

```
Text(text = "Your text", modifier = Modifier.alpha(ContentAlpha.medium))
```

*Hope it helps!*